# set user agent stylesheet css from javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to override user agent stylesheet css from javascript once the page has loaded. for some reason this isn't working. I'm new to javascript and very basic knowledge of css/less and im trying to learn the best practice on how to achieve this.

my javascript:

```
$(window).ready(function ()
{
    // Remove splash screen after load
    $('.splash').css('display', 'none');
});
```

ive also tried `$('.splash').css('display', 'none !important');` which doesn't work either.

I'm setting the display type in my css so i dont uderstand why its being overriden.

CSS

```
.splash {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2000;
  background: #fff;
  color: #555;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

[image]

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/76wqqft4/

Thanks for the help

Comment: You are looking at the wrong element. Your CSS and JavaScript are both targeting the element with `class="splash"` which is not the `<h1>` element.

Comment: You can't change the user agent CSS, only the author CSS, but any author CSS will override any user agent CSS.

Comment: ahh appologies, its the same problem with the splash div though, ill update the image!

Comment: Try creating a [real test case](http://sscce.org/) so that we can reproduce the problem. Even with the updated screenshot (which doesn't show all the rules being applied anyway) there's no way to reproduce the problem.

Comment: My Bad, there is a spelling mistake in your class name and your jquery selector

Comment: @Quentin, if there wasn't this typo, even setting the parent's `display:none` would have affected the inner H1

Comment: @Kaiido — It wouldn't have affected the list of properties applied to the H1. `display` is not inherited.

Comment: @Quentin, not its properties, but its visiblity. I may be wrong, but I'm pretty sure you can't have a visible element inside an other one with `display: none`set. `display:block` is relative to the parent, so in a way it is inherited.

Comment: @Kaiido — The point of looking at the rules is to see which rules are changing the `display` property, where them come from, and in which order they are applied. It isn't to determine what the final value that is applied actually is.

Comment: But i'm quite sure what OP was trying to do is just to hide this text displayed in his page. He didn't talked about debugging tools

Comment: @Kaiido — Other than putting, in the question, a screenshot of the debugging tool they were trying to use to debug the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question jQuery Selector is having `.splash` as the class name and in the screenshot, class name which is suppose to hide is `.spash`. Change the class name for desired output.

Comment: well that embarrassing. maybe I should get another coffee in me.

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple typing mistake, in your html it says "spash" and in jquery and css its "splash" :)